# Хранение данных при использования приложения android

Tags: java, android

При открытии Активити начинается загрузка данных,в основе это json ответ от сервера, при новом открытии того же Активити данные загружаются снова, как и куда можно сохранить данные? то же происходит при смене ориентации телефона

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так же, если нужно использовать данные в рамках активной сессии приложения, то можно обойтись без сохранения данных. Достаточно записывать данные в статическая переменную, предварительно создав ее вне активити. Далее проверять, если она не пуста, то пользоваться данными, если пуста - запросить и присвоить данные.

Answer (score 0):

Данные на телефоне можно сохранять в файл или в БД SQLite. На счет как, зависит от того где именно вы решите хранить данные.